# How to search for and connect to a scanner in flutter windows app?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, image-scanner

Iam trying to make a flutter windows application that can connect to a scanner device and get the image data from it, but i can't seem to find any packages that help with that so if anyone can give me the link of a library or a tutorial that can help with that.
Thanks in advance.

i have tried searching but all the packages i have found are directed to android and ios only.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: currently not possible to create a Flutter app for Windows that can connect to a scanner device and obtain image data. Flutter only supports creating apps for Android, iOS, and the web, and does not have built-in support for accessing hardware devices such as scanners. 
 you could create a Flutter web app that uses JavaScript to access the scanner device, but this would only work on certain web browsers that support the necessary APIs. You can find more information on how to access scanner devices in the web in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

I've ported the C++ code from https://github.com/twain/twain-samples and created an open source project https://github.com/yushulx/flutter_twain_scanner.

The plugin is available on https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twain_scanner

The full code to scan documents from a connected scanner on Windows desktop:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_twain_scanner/flutter_twain_scanner.dart';

import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  final _flutterTwainScannerPlugin = FlutterTwainScanner();
  String? _documentPath;
  List<String> _scanners = []; // Option 2
  String? _selectedScanner;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    // We also handle the message potentially returning null.
    try {
      platformVersion = await _flutterTwainScannerPlugin.getPlatformVersion() ??
          'Unknown platform version';
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter TWAIN Scanner'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        MaterialButton(
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              List<String>? scanners =
                                  await _flutterTwainScannerPlugin
                                      .getDataSources();

                              if (scanners != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _scanners = scanners;
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text('List Scanners')),
                        DropdownButton(
                          hint: Text(
                              'Select a scanner'), // Not necessary for Option 1
                          value: _selectedScanner,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedScanner = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: _scanners.map((location) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(location),
                              value: location,
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (_selectedScanner != null) {
                                int index =
                                    _scanners.indexOf(_selectedScanner!);
                                String? documentPath =
                                    await _flutterTwainScannerPlugin
                                        .scanDocument(index);
                                setState(() {
                                  _documentPath = documentPath;
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text('Scan Document')),
                      ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                    height: 600,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: _documentPath == null
                          ? Image.asset('images/default.png')
                          : Image.file(
                              File(_documentPath!),
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              width: 600,
                              height: 600,
                            ),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```